# handling 'this' in an addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, this, addeventlistener

I want to call `handleRangeUpdate` in such a way that it would be dependent on the event which it is called so that it can decide to execute `console.log(this.value)`

However upon passing `e` into `handleRangeUpdate` through the `addEventListener`, the value of `this` then changes from `input` to `window`, or to `handleRangeUpdate` not being called at all, depending if I used arrow functions or tried to bind/call `this` to the listener.

My issue and question is this (no pun intended), how do I pass the proper *this* to the listener in `addEventListener`?

```
const sliders = player.querySelectorAll('.player__slider');
sliders.forEach(slider => slider.addEventListener('change', handleRangeUpdate));
sliders.forEach(slider => slider.addEventListener('mousemove', handleRangeUpdate));
```

and the html for the sliders:

```
<input type="range" name="volume" class="player__slider" min="0" max="1" step="0.05" value="1">
<input type="range" name="playbackRate" class="player__slider" min="0.5" max="2" step="0.1" value="1">
```

Comment: simple ... don't use arrow function notation - i.e. use the right tool for the job, a chisel isn't good at hammering nails

Comment: You have to define `handleRangeUpdate` using `function`, otherwise it is not possible to pass a dynamic `this` to it. If you insist on using arrow functions or bound functions for some reason, you can only use `e.currentTarget` and not `this`.

Comment: You need to add an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so we can help you.

Comment: Arrow functions are NOT just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this will work but having a code sample from codepen on your end would be more helpful. You need to bind the handlers. `addEventListener` will always execute the handler function in the `this` context of the element or object that triggered the event.

```
const sliders = player.querySelectorAll('.player__slider');
sliders.forEach(slider => slider.addEventListener('change', () => handleRangeUpdate.bind(this)));
sliders.forEach(slider => slider.addEventListener('mousemove', ()=> handleRangeUpdate.bind(this)));
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong in the code that the OP has posted up to now. Your snippet however will definitely not work.